# How to select multiple images for deletion on the Olympus E-M5?

Tags: olympus-omd

The manual of the Olympus OMD E-M5 says it is possible to select multiple images for deletion, but does not mention *how*.

Sorry if this sounds like a silly question but, *how can I select multiple images for deletion*?

So far, I honestly could not find out a way to do this.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't do this. Ever. It is too easy to make a mistake and then your pictures are gone! SD cards are cheap, download them, and delete them off your computer.

Comment: @PaulCezanne Good for you :-P When I can plan in advance and everything works "as planned" I delete images using my computer. The situation that motivated my question was having a full card while shooting and having _by mistake_ loads of old images inside the card. "Not as planned" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the REC button. A red tick will show up in the top right corner on the selected images.

When finished, press the DEL/trash button.

"Are you sure?" Yes. This will delete all selected images.

Answer (score -1):

Very easy: use the (rec) button when you browse your photo on display mode

Comment: What does the rec button do?